# Spreader cookies

Tags: baking, cookies

Can anyone offer an explanation why I get runny spreaders among my medium-sized cookie batches.

All balls are weighed uniformly before storage in the freezer, before baking. Upon baking, about 1-2 out of 16 would be these horrible runny cookies that spread too early and too wide

While it's easy to assume that these spreaders had less share of choco chips, it's actually the contrary since the spreaded/streched parts actually have choco chips though melted and flattened.

I wonder if anyone can identify the issue.
[image: Find the spreaders in the 2nd and 3rd line]

Comment: They look like tasty homemade cookies to me, what's the issue?

Comment: Are you using a convection oven or a normal oven? Do you notice a consistent pattern in placement of the spreading cookies?

Comment: Spreading is usually fat related. I'd guess either the pan was over greased  underneath those cookies (you don't really need to grease the pan at all), or there were chunks of unmixed fat in the ones that spread.

Comment: @RossRidge that's interesting because I use parchment paper over several batches. I'm suddenly not sure if I get spreaders on the first batch.

Comment: @Jay convection oven but I don't use the fan because it creates a temp gradient. Elements are electric and above the cookies (as opposed to gas jets at the bottom)

Comment: @GdD thank you for the visual compliment. It's the spreaders that concern me: see the 2 bigger cookies in the photo. They're lovely with the crusty edge, but often prone to breakage and adhesion to other cookies (bad for my wholesale accounts)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I learned how to stop it. Here is how. When you drop your dollop of cookie dough onto your cookie sheet, press it down so it's "pre-spread" out. Then you'll more reliably have right sized and shaped cookies because the dollop isn't melting down so much. You don't need to squash it all out full sized, just push it down so it's not ball shaped anymore.

It helped me a lot with choco-chip cookies.

Comment: Glad to know someone else had the issue. Let me try your suggestion.